# Google Tag Manager iFrame does that break SEO?

Tags: seo, iframe

I have a question that I haven't yet found the answer on regarding iFrames and SEO. From what I have read, it's a general no-no to have them, but if I have the following snippet added into the body of the HTML:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-something"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

What is the consensus on this I'm not sure how this would work?

Comment: Why do you think it would break SEO to have a hidden iframe inside `noscript`?    I can't think of any reason why it would have anything to do with SEO at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe elements containing content you wish to be indexed should be avoided.

There is no problem with iframe elements in general, only if there is content inside it which you wish to be indexed. For Google Tag Manager, this is not the case — the iframe supports the functionality provided by GTM and the GTM iframe does not contain the main content of the page it is placed on.

For more information on Google's indexing of iframe elements, see
[Frames - Google Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en).